# Flutter - Lock specific sections of a TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

In our Flutter app (web), we have a requirement to give end-users the ability to edit a paragraph of text, but need to 'lock' or 'protect' certain parts of the paragraph which serve as placeholders.

Here's a sample paragraph:

> Tenant shall have the option to extend the Term of the Lease for
> {{additional.term.count}} additional {{term.length}} term(s) with
> written notification by Tenant to Landlord
> {{advance.written.notification}} prior to Tenant's Lease expiration.
> The rental terms for the option periods shall be based on
> {{market.rent.percentage}} of the market rents including market
> concessions. In the event the Landlord and Tenant are unable to agree
> on {{market.rent.percentage}} of the market rent, the Landlord and
> Tenant shall proceed to a 3 broker arbitration method

In this case, the edited language between tenants and landlords can change (think negotiation), but the placeholders need to stay constant so their values can be rendered using variable substitution when the agreement is rendered as a whole.

I'm 'new-ish' to Flutter and am trying to determine if this is at all possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be done using inputFormatter from textField with regex or using a mask package, such as mask_text_input_formatter. Consider the fixed parts of your text as the "special characters" in a mask.

Comment: Or, that looks almost exactly like moustache format... and there are good moustache packages in the pub.

Comment: On reviewing the question, the problem is deeper... you'll need essentially read-only parts in the edit box.  But I'm not sure any editing will be possible.  What if I change "shall" to "shall not".